# Reduce -reduce conflict in grammar

Tags: bison, reduce-reduce-conflict

I am getting a reduce/reduce conflict for the following grammar in bison because n is also an epsilon production.

```
m   :                       {$$=line_no;}
    ;
n   :                       {   

                            $$.nl=makelist(line_no);
                            codelines[line_no].opcode=GOTO;
                            codelines[line_no].result=0;
                            line_no++;
                            }
    ;
selection_statement
    : IF '(' expression ')' m statement         %prec THAN
    | IF '(' expression ')' m statement n ELSE m statement
    | SWITCH '(' expression ')' statement
    ;
```

How do I modify this to remove this conflict?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the problem is the epsilon reduction of `n`, which needs to be associated with the shift of the `ELSE`. The problem will occur in exactly the same circumstance as the "ambiguous" `else`, since it will not be clear to which `if` statement the `n` belongs.

The obvious and easy solution is to move the `n` after the `ELSE` since it does not make any difference whether the reduction action happens before or after the shift, and after the shift it is clear even to an `LALR` parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar doesn't seem to use the value of m. So you might as well remove all references to m and its rule.